# Realtime action iPhone Multiplayergame for iPhone via Game Center possible?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

I'm currently building an iPhone action/fun-game with cocos2d. It's a 2D tank game where you have to fight against each other. I started implementing Game Center to support playing online with friends.

When I'm trying it with my (slow) wifi internet connection the game is laggy and delayed.

Is it even possible to use Game Center for this kind of game? Should I support local Wifi/Bluetooth instead of Game Center?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start right [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). Using bluetooth might be an improvement.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean I should use a peer-to-peer connection for realtime games? Doesn't GameCenter automatically checks if both players are in the same network and send it directly to your opponent?

Comment: You can use peer-to-peer or server-client, depending on the needs of your game.

Comment: I decided to only support local multiplayer via Bluetooth and Wifi. I think it was a good decision for a real time action game.

Comment: Bluetooth for me is actually much slower than wifi.  Especially with more than 2 players.